# Tengo un select (html) en el que creo options, quiero borrarlo al inicio y volverlo a crear

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo una web que cada vez que abro una ventana recibe una cantidad en numeros, cada ventana es distinta y se abre en la misma página web como deslizandose, cada una tiene sus numeros asignados, estos numeros yo los muestro en un texto pero también necesito trabajar con ellos, yo cojo cada numero y lo inserto en una variable que se reemplazaria en la sentencia del for por el numero que he colocado yo por lo tanto cada vez recorre el for y crea un select con tanto numeros como se han comparado, si yo abro otra ventana distinta se muestran los numeros de la ventana anterior más los nuevos, por lo tanto para evitar este error, yo lo que queria es que cada vez que se ejecutara este select, para que no recogiera los valores de otra ventana los borrara y imprimira los actuales recogidos en esta ventana, es decir necesito borrar los numeros siempre y luego crearlos nuevamente recorriendo el for, he estado probando durante un rato pero no consigo encontrar el resultado correcto.
Por ejemplo: yo muestro un listado de opciones de 1 al 10 luego lo abro de nuevo y se borra y se muestra de nuevo las opciones esto es posible?

```js
let select = document.getElementById('select')
for(i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
    let option = document.createElement("option");
    let valor = option.value = i;
    let texto = option.text = i;
    select.appendChild(option);                                     
}
```

```html
<select name="select" class="form-control" id="select">
</select>
```

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende ni le encuentro sentido. ¿Por qué quieres crear/borrar lo mismo cada vez?

Comment: Creo que el problema aquí no es el código en sí mismo, sino que no tienes claro el problema o el contexto, me parece confuso lo que dices y no logro entenderlo. Quizá si explicas el problema se podría aportar una solución más simple.

Comment: Este es el típico caso de lo que yo llamo *esclavitud del código*. O sea, tú has implementado un código pensando resolver un problema, pero ese código no resuelve el problema, entonces **te olvidas del problema** y ahora quieres hacer funcionar ese código para que te resuelva el problema sin pensar que **aparte del problema original** tienes un nuevo problema que es el código. En casos como estos se agradece que **te olvides del código** y que trates de explicar el problema simplemente. No deberías nunca querer explicar un problema desde un código, el código existe para resolver ese problema.

Comment: entiendo, pues estoy totalmente en blanco la verdad. No se como solucionarlo

Comment: Te sugiero que nos expliques el problema y el contexto con la mayor claridad posible, mostrando también el código que estás implementando. Así podremos ayudarte, pero sin entender problema y contexto es imposible dar una respuesta. Muchas veces el principal problema es no saber explicar el problema, eso, sumado a un código que no funciona se convierte en un bucle sin salida. La única forma de salir de ese bucle es **explicando el problema**. Cuando tienes claro el problema entonces pasas a resolverlo con un código, no al revés.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas crear una función que reciba como parámetro el total de opciones a agregar (borrando primero las anteriores) y ejecutarla cuando sea necesario. Por ejemplo:

- Al cargar la página, supongo que deberá tener una cantidad de opciones
- Al pasar a otra ventana, para actualizar
- Al hacer clic en un botón o realizar cambios en un *input*

```js
let select = document.getElementById('select')

function fillSelect(num) {
    // Borrar opciones anteriores, se debe recorrer en descendente
    for(let i = select.options.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        select.options[i].remove();
    }
    // Agrega las opciones de acuerdo al parámetro recibido
    for(let i = 1; i <= num; i++){
        let option = document.createElement("option");
        // No declares variables que no vas a usar, solo asigna las propiedades
        option.value = i;
        option.text = i;
        select.appendChild(option);
    }
}

// Ejecutar al cargar la página
fillSelect(5);

// O se puede actualizar con eventos
document.querySelector('#update-select').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    // Si el botón es parte de un formulario, evitar acción por defecto
    e.preventDefault();
    // Obtener número desde input
    let num = parseInt(document.querySelector('#options').value) || 0;
    if(num > 0) {
        // Actualizar solo si el número es mayor que cero
        fillSelect(num);
    }
});
```

```html
<select name="select" class="form-control" id="select">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select><br>

<input type="number" id="options" value="10">
<button id="update-select">Actualizar</button>
```

Comment: Disculpa que conteste tan tarde, muchísimas gracias!! era justo eso lo que necesitaba lo he adaptado a mi código y va perfecto!!! la verdad no tenia ni idea de como solucionar esto, Gracias!